# I can't run Ghostbusters the Videogame on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ghostbusters-the-video-game

Error says:

```
Msg: Texture 'ui\font_calibri.tga' was selected for rendering without being cached
File: texture.cpp
Line: 3798
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, activate Windows Compatibility mode for the game.
- If it can't find the texture files, it might be looking for them in a different (the "default") place. Copy the whole game from your Steam folder to "C:\Program Files\Atari\Ghostbusters"